# "The requested quantity is not available" Back Order Products

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend-error

My store has backorders enabled, everything works as expected when dealing with a quantity of 1 for each product that is available for backorder.

The problem is that when a customer tries to enter a value greater than 1 on the product page or the cart page the error:

> The requested quantity is not available

[image: The requested quantity is not available]

There are no errors logged, products that are `In Stock` allow for the quantities to be updated (provided that there are enough).

Has anyone had this issue and what can I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't locate `The requested quantity is not available` Magento CE 1.9. Are you using an extension that rewrite any of the `Maga_CatalogInventory` classes? I would first do a string search in `app` and see where the error message is set and go from there.

Comment: You are a genius... I've been trying to figure this out for 2 months, it looks like one of my old developers put this check in for a live inventory before I allowed back-orders.

Comment: Just to update, I removed the code and it works. I am truly grateful :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked!

Comment: When i try to update inventory programmatic-ally this result shows the same error message, even if the stock is available, how can i avoid this error message